# Highlight the specific menu tab in mvc layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net or mvc Development, and i'm trying to convert a static html template to asp.net mvc

i have code in layout page for menu Items

- class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index")
- @Html.ActionLink("Destinations","Destinations")
- @Html.ActionLink("Support","Support")
- @Html.ActionLink("About US", "About_US")
- @Html.ActionLink("Blog","Blog")
- @Html.ActionLink("Contact Us","Contact_US")

in static website i can easily paste  class="active" for the specific page to make the specific tab highlighted,as we have to repeat the same code for every static page  but i don't know how to do this in MVC where we have only one layout for all actions.

Answer (score 0):

See below

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText",
    "Action",
    "Controller",
    new { /*routing values, leave empty if nothing specific*/ }, 
    new { @class = "active" /*all html attributes (id, style, rel, etc) goes here*/ })
```